# stretch HTML container to fit size of background image

Tags: html, css, layout, background-image

It's possible to write CSS that stretches a container's background image to fit the container.  But is it possible to do the reverse, that is, write CSS that makes the container resize to fit the background image?

In the past I have used an ugly hack using JQuery (which I'm not happy with, because it depends on the dimensions of the image actually being specified in the image's filename).  So my strong preference is to do this using CSS, but if that's not possible, then I'd also be happy with the cleanest possible Javascript/JQuery solution.

(Side note: this no doubt seems like an odd thing to want to do.  The reason is that I'm working with a rendering engine that spits out an image sized according to certain device parameters.)

Comment: Use jquery and set the variables to equal store the image size. and then use a css. operator to change the content size of width and height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible with just css, but I'm not one to say much of anything is impossible.  I'm not sure what your use-case is but you could embed an img tag inside the element you are setting the background of.  Setting the src of the img tag to the same picture will force the browser to render the parent element at the same dimensions.

Using css you could then render the element hidden, and the background element will render full size.  You could also use jQuery to dynamically inject a hidden img element with the same background image set on the wrapper element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        div .img { visibility: hidden; }
        div { background: url(img.jpg) top left no-repeat; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div><img src="img.jpg" /></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The main consequence of this method is that IE and perhaps other browsers will download the image twice.  Chrome is smart enough to avoid that problem. But I didn't test FF, Safari or Opera.

Answer (score 1):

Elements are unaware of the dimensions of background images.

You need to do this with JavaScript. You can read the image into a variable, then check the dimensions there, and tranfer them to the container.

Comment: How do you recommend extracting the image dimensions from the image data itself?  Are you suggesting that @dbaseman use an XMLHTTPRequest object to read the file from the server and then decrypt the image's meta info?

Comment: No, just use: var tmp = new Image(); tmp.onload=testfunction; tmp.src='...' then in testfunction you can read the image's size